# ArcMap hangs exporting data to MPK

Tags: arcmap, map-package

When trying to export a map as an MPK, ArcMap gets stuck at "Preparing Data (Folder Size 0KB)". I have tried a couple different MXDs and they all have this problem.

I am working off a server with a not-so-great connection, but the connection isn't *that* bad.  Any thoughts on what could be causing this?

Comment: How large are the datasets within the MXD? Is everything set to the same CRS? Are you working with Rasters and Vectors? These can all effect the time it takes to export to mpk. How long have you let it run?

Comment: There are only 2 layers, 1 raster and 1 vector. Vector is v small, raster is about 1.7 GB. Maybe it is just that the files are too big, but I've let it run for twenty minutes now and no change...